# Find type of all properties of response in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a functionality that was previously developed and the code is not optimized.

Here is the code:

```
function myFunc(response) {
    setChekBoxValue($("#test1"), response.test1);
    setChekBoxValue($("#test2"), response.test2);
    setTextBoxValue($("#test3"), response.test3);
    setTextBoxValue($("#test4"), response.test4);
    setChekBoxValue($("#test5"), response.test5);
    setRadioButtonValue("test6", response.test6);
    setRadioButtonValue("test7", response.test7);
}
```

The response is the all c# class properties and their values I get.
But the problem is class properties are over 100 and that's why the set functions are written 100 times which is not seem proper to me.

So what I need in help is how can I check the type of particular property of response in jQuery or JavaScript.
e.g. "test1" is of type "boolean" and "test3" is of type "string".

If I get the type of property then I can use the switch case based on that.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean `typeof` ? `typeof response.test1`

Comment: `typeof response.test1` . https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/typeof

Comment: Yes but to iterate over all the properties I have used for loop      for (var element in response) {
        var varType = $.type(element);
    } But here I always get varType = "string"

Comment: Please add some information, so I can improve my answer.

Comment: Please take a look at the "[mcve]" and "ask" guidelines; as it is your question doesn't have enough information that we - who have never seen any part of your code before today - can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ok David I will take care of it in future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript `for .. in ..` loop iterates over the keys. To get the elements, do it like this:

```js
var obj = {"a":1, "b":2};
for(var key in obj) {
  var element = obj[key];
 console.log(element);
}
```

This gives 1 and 2.

Comment: Hello Adder, It works fine but there is one issue. If I get element as string and its value is null then "typeof element" gives "Object" as result. How can I get it as string?

Comment: I see that behaviour. I guess you'll have to check for null-ness separately.